# Return the position first position two strings are different

Tags: java, string, loops, passwords, acm-java-libraries

i can't figure out how i am supposed to return the first position org and check are different. Do i have to use substrings?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class CheckPasswords extends ConsoleProgram
{
  public void run()
  {  

   while(true)
   {
      String org = readLine("Enter Password: ");
      String check = readLine("Confirm Password: ");

      if(org.equals(check))
      {
        println("Password Confirmed");
      }
      else
      {
        println("Passwords do not Match");
        //???
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to just check if they are equal or not , you can use:

```
int val = org.compareTo(check);
```

It will return 0 if they are equal, negative value if org is *before* check , else positive value if org is *after* check.

If you really want to return the first position where they are unequal, use this function:

```
int firstMismatch(String org, String check)
{
    int limit = (org.length()>check.length())?org.length():check.length();
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        try{
        if(org.charAt(i)!=check.charAt(i))
        {
             return i; //If one of the strings end, that's the position they are different, otherwise there is a mismatch. Either way, just return the index of mismatch
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             if(org.length()!=check.length())
            {

             return(i); //Execution comes here only when length of strings is unequal
         //Exception occurs because first string is smaller than
         // the second or vice versa. Say if you use "fred" and"fredd" as org and check 
         //respectively, "fred" is smaller than "fredd" so accessing org[4] is not allowed.   
         //Hence the exception.
          }

           System.out.println("Problem encountered"); //Some other exception has occured.
          return(-2);
        }  
    }
    return(-1); //if they are equal, just return -1



}
```

**EDIT :** And in your code, call as follows:

```
public class CheckPasswords extends ConsoleProgram
{
  public void run()
  {  

  while(true)
  {
  String org = readLine("Enter Password: ");
  String check = readLine("Confirm Password: ");
  int mismatchPosition = firstMisMatch(org,check);  
  if(mismatchPosition==-1)
  {
    println("Password Confirmed");
  }
  else
  {
    println("Passwords do not match from position "+mismatchPosition);

      }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem on int limit = org.length()>check.length?org.length():check:length();

Comment: Try with my edit. I have added brackets to that line.

Comment: putting that into the context of the whole program would help

Comment: I have been getting " The method firstMisMatch(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) is undefined for the type CheckPasswords" error. I really appreciate the help man.

Comment: This is not a built in function. This is a function I wrote for you :). So put the function inside your class.

Comment: Not a problem :) Glad to help out. :)

Comment: Seems like there is a problem if the passwords are not same length

Comment: Simplified my function. This should work. Please check my edited function, try and let me know.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work if you input something like "fredd" for org and "fred" for check

Comment: or if it's the other way around

Comment: In case of fredd or fred what does it return?

Comment: it crashes the program

Comment: Does it give NullPointerException?

Comment: Check if it prints value of limit as 5 ( for "fredd" and "fred") before crashing.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4 -- is the error

Comment: Check my edited answer, hopefully this will work for all cases.

Comment: Check my comments in that code for the explanation for that exception :)

Comment: sorry change that to stringindex outof boundsexception

Comment: thanks, but one problem. im getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException cannot be resolved to a type. Im still very new so i appreciate the help

Comment: Damn now im getting, StringIndexOutofBoundsException cannot be resolved to a type, so no :(

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Do one thing, change that StringIndexOutofBoundsException in the catch statement to just Exception and try.

Comment: Ah the good old Exception solved the case eh? Note that Exception is generic and will catch practically any exception, and it encompasses StringIndexOutofBoundsException. Dunno y your compiler doesn't recognize it though :). No problem, glad to help out.

Comment: P.S.: An upvote would be nice :) (especially for the comments) :D

Comment: -1 for use an exception for flow control, catching `Exception`, and failing to do anything to log it despite the fact that it could be nearly anything.

Comment: If you see the flow of comments here, we resorted to Exception due to a specific problem on his compiler. While I agree with you that an exception can be anything, in this case, this is the only way an exception can occurs, that is through StringOutofBoundsException. If it does happen that there is some other cause of exception, this can be further refined by a simple if(org.length()!=check.length()){return i;} in the catch, essentially giving him what he wants.

Comment: And yes i think it was a problem with my compiler.

Comment: Spoonman : @SoftwareMonkey has a point. Since you have used the Exception, please incorporate the change i specified in my previous comment. I shall edit my answer for the same.

Comment: @Gautham: The point is that causing an exception for flow control is a well-known anti-pattern in programming. Even if he adds the check you suggest *in the exception handling*, it still swallows an exception silently, which is bad practice and should be actively dishabituated (even if, in this case, you can demonstrate only one exception could be raised, one has to examine the code to know that to be the case). See my answer for how this *should* be done, with proper bounds checking. (And, frankly, a cleaner, more succinct and arguably more correct solution.)

Comment: @Software Monkey: Duly noted :-) thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest and clearest way

```
private int getPositionWhereTextDiffer(String a, String b) {
    int position = 0;
    while ( b.length() > position &&
            a.length() > position &&
            a.charAt(position) == b.charAt(position)) {
        position++;
    }
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be:

```
static public int indexOfDiff(String one, String two) {
    if(one!=null && two!=null) { 
        if(one==null || two==null) { 
            return 0;            
            }
        else {
            int ln=(one.length()<two.length() ? one.length() : two.length());
            for(int xa=0; xa<ln; xa++) {
                if(one.charAt(xa)!=two.charAt(xa)) { return xa; }
                }
            if(one.length()!=two.length()) {
                return ln;
                }
            }
        }
    return -1;
    }
```

This returns `-1` if the strings are in fact equal (including if both are `null`), which generally should not be the case in practical use since the string will already be know to be different.

Comment: If you use "fredd" for enter password and "fred" for confirm password it returns as equal. might need a fix

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean isDifferent = false;
if(org!=null && check!=null) {
if(org.length()!=check.length()) {
    System.out.println("String are diff at position, "+check.length()+1);
} else {
    int mismatchPos = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< org.length();i++) {
        if(org.charAt(i)!=check.charAt(i)) {
            isDifferent = true;
            mismatchPos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isDifferent) {
        System.out.println("String are diff at position, "+mismatchPos);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Still, I dont get why you are identifying where two passwords are diff, you can only identify whether they are same or different

Comment: seems to have a null pointer exception error on if(org.length()!=check.length())

Comment: @user3291384 Now check it

Comment: This won't event compile due to accessing `i` out of scope.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey Thanks for pointing out.The code was not written on the editor, hence was an issue. Also it was written to let the questioner get an idea of implementation.

Comment: @Aditya If i use something like "fredd"(for password) and "fred"(for confirm password) it returns 41, weird.